Open/edit LLF files
We have an unknown file format at work that handles templates for a label printer and we want to be able to edit those templates so we can change them.
Is there any software out there free or paid that can handle .LLF file types?
At the moment we are assuming that that’s the template file type as it’s the only thing we can see on the system. Thanks in advance!
Sources online suggest it’s IITM software by unknown publisher and when we search for that it only comes up with Institute of Technology India so a bit confused.

Have you try to open such file with text editor, notepad for example?

Try FileViewPro
It opens and edits many files including .llf files. It is avaliable for Windows and Linux.
And I am not asdociated with it.
